# CF11 LocalHost 404 Issue

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I've just recently installed CF11 on a new machine but I'm encountering the below issue when trying to navigate to the localhost directory in a browser.

[image]

On my previous machine which was using CF10 I was able to get the directory listings and navigate through folders to specific pages so is it some setting that I am missing?

I can navigate to CFAdmin okay and have added a whole range of aliases in my server.xml file which I can navigate to, as well as adding the CFIDE and WEB-INF ones.

As an aside, I also seem to get that silly 404 badge in front of CFs debug output when I try and navigate to a page that doesn't yet exist. Is there a way to switch it off?

If you need more details let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it work if you add `index.cfm` to the end of that URL?

Comment: No I still get the same error. It's weird because I get the CF debug info in the background but that stupid 404 error badge and header is in front of it. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Is there an `index.cfm` file in the root directory?

Comment: Have you added the `/jakarta` virtual directory? This should point to `{your-cf-root}/config/wsconfig/{n}/` where _n_ is an integer for your connector instance (probably 1 if you've only installed once). It uses this VD to execute its `isapi_redirect.dll` connector, which handles a number of things